# What is an '"Invalid Impression Limit" error?

Tags: synchronization, facebook-ads-api

We are using the Ads API and intermittently we have been receiving back an "Invalid Impression Limit" error. However, we are actually syncing over budget changes to a campaign which seems unrelated and which does not include any data related to impressions (updates to the amount but not the type). Any insight into what this might mean?